# Getting the key value of appSettings from a different config files

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a config file named Refer.config which contains the appSettings as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Database" value="CouchDB"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now in the web.config i have referenced it as:

```
<appSettings file="C:\Users\312171\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite4\Refer.config">

  </appSettings>
```

Now in the cs file i m trying to access the key value of appSettings like this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filetype = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
        testvalue.Text = string.Format("The key value is:",filetype);
    }
```

But it is not returning the key value...
What mistake i have made?? Please help me out..

Comment: Does your program has sufficient permission to read file? Any exception is it throwing?

Comment: @Mohan
No exception is been thrown.. It jus displays as" The key value is: "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer by trying like this in web.config...

```
<appSettings file="Refer.config"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `configSource` attribute if you are on .net 2.0 or above.

```
<appSettings configSource="Refer.config">
</appSettings>
```

**Note that the path must be relative.**

[File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is supposed to take a relative path

> File specifies a relative path to an external file containing custom
>   application configuration settings. The specified file contains the
>   same kind of settings that are specified in the , , and
>    elements and uses the same key/value pair format as those
>   elements.
>
> The path specified is relative to the main configuration file. For a
>   Windows Forms application, this would be the binary folder (such as
>   /bin/debug), not the location of the application configuration file.
>   For Web Forms applications, the path is relative to the application
>   root, where the web.config file is located.
>
> Note that the runtime ignores the attribute if the specified file can
>   not be found.

Comment: I have tried in the way u specified.. But it throws an exception as
"The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section"